# How to install python3.6 on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: python-3.6, apt-get, ubuntu-22.04

I need to install this specific python version, to prepare a developer environment, because I'm maintaining a system with multiple libraries based on python 3.6.9.
I recently installed Ubuntu 22.04 on my laptop, but I had no success trying to install this python version.

I tried to install [with apt-get after adding the deadsneak repository](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1231543/problem-with-creating-python-3-6-virtual-environment-on-ubuntu-20-04), but this python version is not available.

I tried [installing from source by compiling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70395169/how-to-install-python-3-6-on-ubuntu-21-10), but it did not work.  Running `sudo make altinstall` exited with this error:

```
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
make: *** [Makefile:1112: altinstall] Erro 139
```

Answer (score 80, accepted):

I have faced the same problems and could make it work by adding some additional flags when running `./configure`

Here are my steps:

**Step 1 – Prerequsities**

```
sudo apt-get install -y make build-essential libssl-dev zlib1g-dev \
libbz2-dev libreadline-dev libsqlite3-dev wget curl llvm libncurses5-dev \
libncursesw5-dev xz-utils tk-dev libffi-dev liblzma-dev \
libgdbm-dev libnss3-dev libedit-dev libc6-dev
```

**Step 2 – Download Python 3.6**

```
wget https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.6.15/Python-3.6.15.tgz

tar -xzf Python-3.6.15.tgz
```

**Step 3 – Compile Python Source**

```
cd Python-3.6.15
./configure --enable-optimizations  -with-lto  --with-pydebug
make -j 8  # adjust for number of your CPU cores
sudo make altinstall
```

**Step 4 – Check the Python Version**

```
python3.6 -V
```

Comment: This works like a cham. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks a lot! This helped me, I had the same problem! If you have more than one CPU core and enough memory, `make -j 8 altinstall` will use, for example, 8 cores for building.

Comment: So useful an answer. Helped me

Comment: Gosh, you've saved my hair! 

I'd contributed some edits to your answer, and also thanks @peschü!

Comment: Just to give y'all a ballpark, it took about 15-30 minutes - didn't accurately time, went for coffee - on Intel Core i7-6700HQ .

Comment: It seems like installing packages through pip go from source this way (slow), and packages without sources on pypi like tensorflow are a pain to install. I've discarded this method of using legacy python versions and simply ported some of the legacy code of the package I use. I might have done something wrong, but please consider this before going through this rabbit hole.

Comment: How to uninstall this? I want to reinstall it

Comment: How to avoid the prompt for geographic region, so that this can be done in a Dockerfile?

Comment: For anyone else running into this, the component that expects user input is the `tk-dev` component. Just removing this from the installation - and the Python3.6 installation succeeded. Also, to access pip, use `pip3.6` (and `python3.6` for python). Just calling `pip3` won't work.

Comment: @DanNissenbaum this can be done in a Dockerfile also if we do `ARG DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive` as per https://serverfault.com/a/797318/940772

Comment: For everyone finding this who wants to have a `libpython3.6m.so.1.0`  file: add `--enable-shared` to the `./configure` command.

Answer (score 5):

As on Aug 2nd 2023, if anyone is still stuck with `Segmentation fault (core dumped)` issue. Here's the solution that worked for me. Thanks to Issue45700 - https://bugs.python.org/issue45700.

Ubuntu 22.04 comes with gcc 11. So let us install gcc-10 and compile Python with it.

Below are the steps to incorporate Workaround1 mentioned in Issue45700  -

```
apt-get install gcc-10 -y
< Download and extract python >
CC="gcc-10" ./configure
< Install python using make >
```

You can use additional flags mentioned in https://stackoverflow.com/a/72135545/8721632

Comment: For me gcc-9 works, you gave me a idea how to fix.

Answer (score 2):

If you need it to install with pyenv, you could try this one:

```
$ sudo apt install clang -y
$ CC=clang pyenv install 3.6.9
```