# How to install Odoo v12 in Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: ubuntu, odoo

I am trying to install odoo v12 in Ubuntu 22.04 using venv with python3.6. This is what I have done so far.

1. I installed python3.6 using the following tutorial. [How to install python3.6 on Ubuntu 22.04][1]
   [1]: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72102435/how-to-install-python3-6-on-ubuntu-22-04

   which python3.6

   /usr/local/bin/python3.6
2. I created an environment using the previous installed version of python

   /usr/local/bin/python3.6 -m venv ./odoo12/
3. I activated the environment and installed all requirements of odoo successfully. Without showing any error.
4. I run the odoo-bin inside the virtual environment

   python3 odoo-bin --addons-path="./addons" -d odoo12
   python3 odoo-bin --addons-path="./addons" -d odoo12
   It runs, but showing some warnings,

   2022-10-25 22:38:36,196 6987 WARNING ? py.warnings: /home/ernesto/Programming/odoo12/odoo/http.py:1334: ResourceWarning: unclosed file <_io.BufferedReader name='/home/ernesto/Programming/odoo12/odoo/addons/test_new_api/**manifest**.py'>
   manifest_data = open(manifest_path, 'rb').read()

and when I open the browser and type http://127.0.0.1:8069/web/login the server stops, and shows an error

```
python3: Python/compile.c:3021: compiler_nameop: Assertion `!_PyUnicode_EqualToASCIIString(name, "None") && !_PyUnicode_EqualToASCIIString(name, "True") && !_PyUnicode_EqualToASCIIString(name, "False")' failed.
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Whats is causing those errors, and how can I install odoo v12 in Ubuntu 22.04
[1]: [How to install python3.6 on Ubuntu 22.04](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72102435/how-to-install-python3-6-on-ubuntu-22-04)

Comment: Hi Ernesto, first of all : have you checked the open/close-brackets {} in your manifest.py file ?

Comment: Concerning compiler error, you could try another Python version (lower or higher) because  it seems to be caused by a Python library (Pytest) : https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest/issues/7322 ( see https://bugs.python.org/issue40870 ; https://github.com/python/cpython/issues/85047 )

Comment: fix compatibility issue on Python 3.8.4 : https://github.com/nestorsalceda/mamba/pull/151

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should install python 3.8 and retry.

Also when dealing with multiple version of Python, always specify the version in the CLI

python3 -> python3.6